# How to count number of packets send by a node?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, csv, plot

I have a CSV file that contains the following columns: source, destination, packet type (UDP or ICMP), description (explain the type of the ICMP packet).

I want to write Python code to parse through the data, counting the number of sent packets per each source/node and plot that.

Can you kindly advise me how can I do that? Examples or tutorials will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question; it's too broad as-is, and requires more effort on your part before the community can help. You need to take this one step at a time. First search the internet for something like `python how to parse csv file` and convert your data set into a Python structure. It sounds like you'd want to create a `dict` to relate each node with the packet count. Once you have that, figure out how to plot it separately. Good luck!

Comment: I did it in R, thanks anyway !!